# Lightbox2 doesn't open html content and links

Tags: navigation, javascript

I installed [Lightbox2](http://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/lightbox2-7.x-1.0-beta1.tar.gz) module and I tried to link an image to a webpage, say `google.com`, this is my code

```
<a href="https://www.google.com/" rel="lightframe[][This is Google]"><img  src="<?php print $base_url;?>/sites/all/themes/MY-THEME/image/fp/map.jpg"></a>
```

but it displays nothing in Lightbhox. This is the print screen of the Lightbox using Firebug

[image]

as you can see there is nothing in body.

Comment: Look at your browser error console: REFUSED TO DISPLAY IN A FRAME BECAUSE IT SET 'X-FRAME-OPTIONS' TO 'SAMEORIG, ie it is a cross domain restriction. This works: <a href="https://maps.google.co.in/maps/ms?ll=19.086522,72.89492&amp;spn=0.001328,0.002642&amp;t=m&amp;z=19&amp;iwloc=0004da9d79b2aac93619b&amp;msa=0&amp;msid=208618496919443620091.0004da9d6f3c4668ebdfa&output=embed"rel="lightframe">google map</a>

Comment: And probably not of much help, but if you install this [extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ignore-x-frame-headers/gleekbfjekiniecknbkamfmkohkpodhe/related) for Chrome it strips away the X-Frame headers. Otherwise just append &output=embed to the url and set the other parameters as needed.

Comment: @J.Reynolds you are right, then what shall I do to link to google? I also added this code `header('X-Frame-Options: GOFORIT');` but didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link works to get google search in the ligtbox:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/custom?q=&btnG=Search"rel="lightframe">Search</a>
```

I got it from this post: [How to show google.com in an iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8700636/how-to-show-google-com-in-an-iframe)

Comment: thanks, for google map adding `&output=embed` works as well